# Proper re-execution of coroutine?

Tags: lua, coroutine

I'm creating a game using lua; I need a timer to run during game intermissions as well as during game rounds. The game initially executes with an intermission of 15 seconds. The timer runs fine in this instance, but subsequent calls to the function do not seem to trigger it at all...any tips?

I've tried swapping my coroutine creation method to coroutine.wrap() instead of coroutine.create().
When successfully running after the first call, the status of the coroutine still appears to be yielding.

Simplified logic shown here: Where seconds is an int and ending is a Boolean

```
module.startTimer = coroutine.create(function(seconds,ending)
    wait()
print("Timer starting with: "..seconds.." seconds...round ending: "..tostring(ending))
while seconds > -1 do
    wait(1)
    seconds = seconds - 1
end
if ending == true then
    coroutine.yield(module.startTimer)
else
    coroutine.yield(module.startTimer)
end
end)
```

First Call (works):

```
print(coroutine.status(module.startTimer))
coroutine.resume(module.startTimer,15,false)
wait(1)
print(coroutine.status(module.startTimer))
```

prints: suspended, suspended

Second Call (doesn't work): Where RoundLength.Value is a verifiable int value (300) that successfully prints.

```
print(coroutine.status(module.startTimer))
coroutine.resume(module.startTimer,CURRENT_ROUND:FindFirstChild("RoundLength").Value,true)
wait()
print(coroutine.status(module.startTimer))
wait(CURRENT_ROUND:FindFirstChild("RoundLength").Value)
```

Prints nothing, no execution, startTimer does not print status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood Lua's coroutines (they're different from normal coroutines, because they are asymmetric), though I can't be certain.

As written, the function will loop until time runs out, then yields itself (?), such that its own function value will be returned from the `coroutine.resume` call.

As soon as it's resumed, it starts again from the `couroutine.yield` call, reaches the end of the function, and returns, ending the coroutine's execution.